# The DLL "vsperf140.dll": the specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

Today I made a new build of my web-application (simple aspx-web-application). When I tried to load it on my server into IIS and navigated to the startpage I got following exception:

> Die DLL "vsperf140.dll": Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
>   (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E) kann nicht geladen werden.

(means: the DLL "vsperf140.dll": the specified module could not be found.)

also the stacktrace doesn't help me a lot:

> [DllNotFoundException: Die DLL "vsperf140.dll": Das angegebene Modul
>   wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E) kann nicht
>   geladen werden.]    _CAP_Enter_Function_Managed(Int32 , Int32 , Int32
>   ) +0    ASP.global_asax..ctor() +23
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler
>   verursacht.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +232    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1122
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) +128    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args,
>   CultureInfo culture) +18
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[]
>   args) +60
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +260
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler
>   verursacht.]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +9930568
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

any idea what the problem could be? Searched in google - but seems that nobody knows something about that vsperf140.dll...

Comment: Hi Matthias, did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @ChandlerTribbiani seems like this came with the performance-profiler. Removing the project and pulling it from TFS again solved my issue. One of these moments when I was happy, using a source control :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From the OP in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673299/the-dll-vsperf140-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found#comment70378353_34673299):*

Seems like this came with the performance profiler. Removing the project and pulling it from TFS again solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Removed the references of AspNetHelper in web.config.
2. Rebuild the whole application and then deployed to new packages on my server.

(Removing the AspNetHelper in web config directly in server didn't solve my issue)